# priority queue clear method

Tags: c++, stl

How do I delete all elements from a priority queue?  That means how do I destroy a priority queue?
advanced thanks for your answer.  Is there any clear- or erase-like method?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The priority_queue interface doesn't have a clear() method (for no good reason I've ever been able to discern). A simple way to clear it is just to assign a new, empty queue:

```
priority_queue <int> q;
// use it
q = priority_queue <int>(); // reset it
```

Comment: @russell What makes you think that? All Standard Library containers and adaptors are assignable.

Comment: @Neil: If the priority queue was a container of pointers, wouldn't the owner have to delete each element?

Comment: @andand Sure, but the same is true for queues. And in either case you probably want a queue of smart pointers, in which case the problem (probably) goes away.

Comment: @Neli: oh,sorry.it works,it was my mistake.thanx for ur help.

Comment: q = decltype(q)();

Comment: This is not exception safe, unlike a `clear()` method, because it constructs a temporary `priority_queue` object, and creating that temporary can throw an exception.

Comment: If you use a std::vector as an underlying type, is this solution keep the already allocated reserved space like clear() does ? I don't think so. So this solution is not as efficient as a clear method.

Answer (score 10):

`priority_queue` doesn't have a clear method. It may be that this is for interface simplicity, or because it there may be situations in which elements must be destroyed in priority-order, making a generic clear function unsafe.

Regardless, the following code block includes two functions to clear priority queues. The first works by building a temporary instance of a wrapper class around the priority_queue and then using this to access the underlying storage object, which is assumed to have a `clear()` method. The second works by replacing the existing priority_queue with a new queue.

I use templating so that the functions can be recycled time and again.

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class S, class C>
void clearpq(priority_queue<T, S, C>& q) {
    struct HackedQueue : private priority_queue<T, S, C> {
        static S& Container(priority_queue<T, S, C>& q) {
            return q.*&HackedQueue::c;
        }
    };
    HackedQueue::Container(q).clear();
}

template <class T, class S, class C>
void clearpq2(priority_queue<T, S, C>& q){
    q=priority_queue<T, S, C>();
}

int main(){
    priority_queue<int> testq, testq2;

    //Load priority queue
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        testq.push(i);

    testq2=testq;

    //Establish it is working
    cout<<testq.top()<<endl;
    testq.pop();
    cout<<testq.top()<<endl;
    testq.pop();

    //Clear it and prove that it worked
    clearpq(testq);
    cout<<testq.size()<<endl;

    //Use the second clearing function
    cout<<testq2.size()<<endl;
    clearpq2(testq2);
    cout<<testq2.size()<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a clean and simple method to clear any `priority_queue` (and `queue`, and most other containers as well):

```
template <class Q>
void clearQueue(Q & q) {
    q = Q();
}
```

Since it's a template, you don't have to remember all the template parameters.

Example:

```
std::priority_queue<MyType> simpleQueue;
std::priority_queue<MyType, std::deque<MyType>, MyHashFunction> customQueue;

// ... later ...

clearQueue(customQueue);
clearQueue(simpleQueue);
```

Comment: Does this work?  priority_queue documentation says the operator=() requires the source and destination PQs must have same size, or operator=() will throw.  Also, you can't assign PQs where the comparison function is a lambda (at least I couldn't get it to work).   The solution that worked best for me is just to use "new" and "delete" and use a ptr to priority_queue.

Comment: @Bogatyr where did you get that information?
According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/operator%3D) this would work fine and for the `operator=()` none of the requirements you stated are listed there.
You are correct, though, that this won't work if you didn't use the default constructor for the original instance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the std::priority_queue::c method in combination with the std::vector::clear method or assign a new container to clear the contents of a priority queue. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MyPriorityQueue : public std::priority_queue<T>
{
public:
    void clear() {
        this->c = std::vector<T>();
    }
};

int main() {
    MyPriorityQueue<int> pq;
    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(2);
    pq.push(3);

    pq.clear();

    std::cout << "The priority queue is now empty" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

depending on the size of the container, you may just pop out the elements from the queue since it can be faster than memory allocation, so you have to test both methods an compare the empirical results

Answer (score 0):

As any C++ STL reference will show you, the STL Priority Queue class does not have a function like 'clear' or 'erase'.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/

It is a container class, and as such, a very simple destructor is generated by the compiler (in most cases).  If your priority queue uses only locally-allocated information in its nodes, then this should work fine for clearing out the memory.

However, if you have dynamically allocated memory for the information in your priority queue, you will need to manually create a 'clear'-like function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In C++ "static" is not the opposite of "dynamic". The items in a PQ will not be allocated statically.

Answer (score 0):

```
priority_queue<int> a;
a.push(10);
a.push(9);
a.push(8);
a   =   {};
a.push(1);
a.push(4);
a.push(6);

while(!a.empty())
    {
    std::cout<< a.top();
    a.pop();
    }
```

results in

```
641
```

So you can simply

```
a = {};
```

Answer (score -2):

there is no clear method supported for priority_queue in c++ but, this below is a good method to clear the priority_queue and has O(log(n)) time

```
while (!pq.empty())
      pq.pop();
```

Comment: The complexity of this is `O(n log(n))` not `O(log(n))`.
This is a terrible idea that solves the problem but wastes a lot of computation for no reason.

Comment: @StefanFabian Not so fast: the mistake aside, depending on the expected number of elements this could still be substantially faster than more popular answers here that cause a new memory allocation.  Complexity analysis is fine in theory, but in practice constants matter.  To say this is terrible is unreasonably harsh.

Comment: @wardw if the number of elements is low, it doesn't matter which method you use, but if the number of elements is high, then this answer is really not good.

Comment: If the number of elements is low then the constant time factor will domainate and any memory reallocation will be much slower than popping a few elements.  My guesss is that in this case it beats the top rated answer nicely but you'd need to measure to find the break-even point.  That said there are other answers that avoid reallocation _and_ the `O(n log n)`, but this still wins on simplicity.  The wider point is that this answer clearly has merit and while helpful to correct it's time complexity it's premature to say this approach is unconditionally a terrible idea.

Comment: I benchmarked: In my case you need at least 8 elements before the number of elements starts to dominate.  That just happens to be my use case: I need to manage just a handful of elements, but many many times over.  In fact, the common case is where all existing elements have been processed so the queue size is often _zero_ - but I can't _guarantee_ it will be zero - so most of the time this approach is essentially free and way better than a reallocation.