# When could std::priority_queue::pop throw an exception

Tags: c++, priority-queue, std, noexcept

The [`pop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) method of `std::priority_queue` is not declared `noexcept`, so in theory could throw an exception. But when might it throw an exception, and what might those exceptions be?

Comment: interesting question. `pop_heap` is not nothrow either.

Comment: Most functions that exhibit UB are not marked `noexcept` so that implementations can throw exceptions if they want.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852140/priority-queue-clear-method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be marked `nothrow`, but isn't.

#### Why `std::priority_queue::pop` could<sup>*</sup> not throw

> ```
> void pop();
> ```
>
> Removes the top element from the priority queue. Effectively calls
>
> ```
> std::pop_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp); c.pop_back();
> ```

`c` is by default an `std::vector`.

> [`[vector.modifiers]/4&5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#modifiers-4)
>
> ```
> void pop_back();
> ```
>
> 4/ *Complexity*: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to the number of the elements erased, but **the assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector *after the erased elements***.
>
> 5/ *Throws*: Nothing unless an exception is thrown by the assignment operator or move assignment operator of T.

<sup>*</sup>So only the destructor of `T` is called and that one cannot throw because of

> [`[requirements.on.functions]/2.4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/requirements#res.on.functions-2.4)
>
> 2/ In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>   [...]
>   2.4/ **if any** replacement function or handler function or **destructor operation exits via an exception**, unless specifically allowed in the applicable *Required behavior:* paragraph.

#### Why is `std::priority_queue::pop` not `nothrow`?

Since an exception thrown from `T::~T` would lead to UB, the implementation can assume it cannot happen and still conform to the Standard. Another way to deal with it is to let such library functions `nothrow(false)` and not dealing with it.

Comment: `erase` and `pop_back` share the description, but it clearly states that "the assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements". In case of `pop_back` there are no elements after the erased element, so it should not throw.